# $A\subset 2^\omega$ has uncountable closure implies that $A$ contains a dense in itself subset

Tags: general-topology

I'm thinking about the following:

Suppose $A\subset \{0, 1\}^\mathbb N$ is a countable set such that $\operatorname{cl} A$ is uncountable. Is it true that there exists $B\subset A$ such that $B$ is dense in itself?

I know that there exists $P\subset \operatorname{cl} A$ such that $P$ is nonempty, closed and dense in itself (i.e. perfect). I tried to construct $B$ using $P$ but I had no success.

I also noticed that if this is true, this is not a general fact since, for instance, $\mathbb N\subset \beta \mathbb N$ is countable, $\operatorname{cl} \mathbb N$ is uncountable, but $\mathbb N$ is discrete.

Comment: Does $B=\varnothing$ qualify?

Answer (score 2):

No. Take, for example, the set $A$ of mid points of the open intervals removed during the construction of the Cantor ternary set $C$. The closure of $A$ is $A \cup C$ but $A$ has no limit points.

Comment: Isn't that for $\mathbb R$ rather than $2^{\omega}$ with the product topology?

Comment: @HenningMakholm But it can easily be ported over to $2^\omega$.

Comment: Hmm, so "porting" it would make $A$ something like the set of all  sequences $\sigma:\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$ such that there is exactly one _odd_ $n$ with $\sigma(n)=1$, and where $\sigma(m)=0$ for every $m> n$. Each element of this $A$ is isolated, but its closure contains every sequence where $\sigma(n)=0$ for all odd $n$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oops, I didn't notice your comment before I posted my (now deleted) answer.